# Adding Custom Attributes in a Sitemap.xml file

Tags: xml, sitemap

I have a publicly facing website. I'm using a sitemap.xml file to tell search engines about the urls on my website. I also have some server-side code that is reading my sitemap.xml file. As it turns out, I want to add some custom attributes to each `<url>` tag. For instance, my sitemap.xml file currently looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.ecofic.com/contact</loc>
    <lastmod>2013-06-04</lastmod>
    <changefreq>never</changefreq>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

I would like to do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.ecofic.com/contact</loc>
    <lastmod>2013-06-04</lastmod>
    <changefreq>never</changefreq>
    <details author="Joe Smith" title="some title">This is a longer description of about the blog post. This will serve as a preview.</details>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

My question is, is that legal? I mean, will search engines ignore my custom tags? Or, will a search engine just see my sitemap, view it as invalid, and ignore the whole file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Custom tags won't be valid you only should use as defined by the schema. your sitemap might be rejected by search engine because of custom tags.